# Polymer JS with Embedded CSS

Tags: javascript, polymer

We have just started implementing web components using Polymer JS in one of our projects .Polymer documentation recommends to include CSS within style tag of the component for performance reasons.

As far as I know one needs to load css files as early as possible in the page load. How does embedding css in the component improves the performance ?

Thanks,
R

Comment: I think you should read the [guide on styling for polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html) first and then see if you still have questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason Polymer encourages including your element's CSS within the element's HTML file itself is so that your styles and your element's markup are both available at the time the element is initialized.

One of the performance boosts here is that the browser does not have to make an extra HTTP request to fetch an external stylesheet: the styles are  already available.

By compiling these resources into one file we also simplify the process of importing and using Polymer components: you just have a `<link rel="import" href="my-element.html">` and you're ready to go. If every Polymer element had its JavaScript and CSS in separate, external files you'd have 2-3 times the HTTP request roundtrips! (providing you aren't [vulcanizing](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize), which you should for production environments)

Another side benefit is a UX one: because your elements are "upgraded" in-place only after Polymer has been loaded (as opposed to immediately when the HTML is parsed into DOM), having the element definition and its styles alongside it means your users never see a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).